# AWS Glue: How to partition S3 Bucket into multiple redshift tables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a basic AWS Glue job set up that reads from an S3 bucket with multiple folders:

```
S3://mybucket/table1
S3://mybucket/table2
S3://mybucket/table3
```

and so on. All of the files in these folders have the exact same format, and I want them to be inserted into different redshift tables in the same database (table1, table2, table3). There seems to be a way to automatically do this from S3 bucket to S3 bucket, but I can't seem to find documentation on how to do it for S3 to Redshift, is this at all possible?

The code I have at the moment is just the basic Glue template code generated for this job, and partition_0 contains the string representation of the folder name:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test", table_name = "all_data_bucket", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("dataField1", "string", "dataField1", "string"), ("partition_0", "string", "partition_0", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")

dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "REDSHIFT", connection_options = {"dbtable": "all_data_table", "database": "dev"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) crawl the data as three separate tables
2) using boto3 list the tables in that database
3) loop through the list and apply your glue code to load data to redshift

Comment: The first two points are fairly straightforward, can you elaborate on #3? are you saying to loop through every item in the table, or loop through the list of 3 tables and apply my code to the entirety of each table at once or something?

Comment: When you crawl your table I believe you will be setting the database where the glue table will reside. In this case if it’s only your 3 tables in that database, you will need to loop through those 3 tables , which U can retrieve using the get_tables function via boto3 glue client. ..... else u don’t even need to crawl. You just loop through the list of s3 locations and apply the same logic on each location....